# How to pass value from django's request to a periodic task in Celery?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, celery

I have a question about how to run and pass args to celery tasks from Django.

What I want:

1 Get keyword (`hashtagName`) from a submitted form

2 Send the name to a periodic task to display it's count on a page every 30 seconds.

Question:

I am not clear about how this should be run. Should I run:
`python manage.py runserver` in one terminal 
and `python manage.py celery worker -B` 
on another terminal window to make the two service run at the same time?

If this is the right way, how could I pass the value from Django to the celery task? As the task will immediately start after my second command.

PS: I read through the celery docs, the part about [periodic task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) is not helpful for my problem since args of my function are from user input.

Thanks!

### UPDATED:

As mentioned in the following answer, I should start a celery task to collecting data. If this is the right way, how should I start the worker? I am still not clear with how to start celery worker and django server at the same time.

Should I run command in terminal like

`$ celery -A proj worker -l info`

`python manage.py runserver`
and call like `taskfunction().delay` in the view function?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a job for celery. That's for background tasks which you can trigger and which can go off and do work independently - complex processing, heavy api calls, etc.

All you need here is a means to refresh information on the page every 30 seconds. That's best done from the browser itself - perhaps with JavaScript with setTimeout, either to either trigger a full page request or to load some  partial content via Ajax.

Comment: As commented for another answer, I should use celery to monitor instead of sending data to front end. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like totally the wrong approach to this problem.

You should be handling this periodic update on the client side, making a an AJAX request for new data when needed.

You make the request to a regular django view, passing the required user input each time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now,for my understanding,this problem should be solved by the following approach: 1) create a celery task to accept args from request to collect data; 2)write a normal django view function to display result. While during display, the front end will send request every 30 seconds; So I was wrong with where to use celery task not about 'should I use celery'. Is this a correct conclusion?

Comment: You would only use celery to schedule some expensive long running task. Is that the nature of the thing you are trying to monitor?

Comment: I guess yes, I am using the streaming api of twitter to monitor some keyworkds's appearance.

Comment: And what is to happen when when that keyword appears?

Comment: When the keyword appears, update the correspond count in database and continue listening until be set to stop.